# SSIS Transfer Database SMO Timeout

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2016, smo

I have to copy a few databases from `SQL Server 2008 R2` to our new server which running `SQL Server 2016`.

I am trying to do this inside `SSIS` project, using `Transfer Database Task` with 'Online' mode as I really don't want to put offline my DBs.

Each database has size > 15 GB.

Unfortunately it's throwing me an error because of Timeout just after 30 seconds. After checking what is actually happening with `SQL Server Profiler` I know that it's failing on `CREATE DATABASE` command - which normally should take ~3 minutes.

Is there any way to increase this `SMO` timeout inside `SSIS` `Transfer Database Task`?

Or maybe there is a better way to copy my whole db on a new server?

Comment: Why not use backup and restore? 15GB is considered a small database.

Comment: @Wendy : It's impossible to restore database from Sql Server 2008 to Sql Server 2016. e: I actually can be wrong. Will try that again. Thank you!

Comment: @Wendy: I can confirm that restoring from Backup was successful. So thank you! But still I wonder if there is any way to do that with Transfer Database Task in Online mode.